# Tratar dados coletados através de uma api JSON

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou coletando dados fornecidos por uma API em JSON.

Com o código abaixo eu consigo visualizar que os dados foram coletados dentro do Subscribe.

Mas fora dele, dentro do próprio arquivo .TS eu não consigo manipular estes dados.

Eu tentei utilizar o promise, mas acho que não utilizei de forma correta, pois também não tive resultado positivo.

Como eu poderia tratar esses dados antes de apresentar na tela?

```
getHour() {
this.hourService.getData()
  .subscribe(
    posts => this.posts = posts,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
  () => console.log(this.posts));     

  console.log(this.posts);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode colocar o retorno desse console.log?

Comment: Opá, sim, já adicionei

Comment: Opa eles so estão disponíveis dentro do subscribe mesmo. Isso pq a chamada http e assíncrona.

Comment: Entendi, e para eu utilizar esses dados fora do subscribe eu precisaria utilizar um async ou await?

Comment: O rxjs e observables e outra forma diferente do async await para lidar com assincronizidade.

Comment: mas se esta dentro do subscribe, pq nao altera os dados, ja que ele foi recebido de forma correta? ou voce usa a sugestao do @EduardoVargas

Comment: @fsi o Eduardo explicou mais abaixo. Já estava achando o que ele disse tbm.

Answer (score 0):

Pensa assim cara, quando vc fazer o hourService.getData uma requisição http e disparada quando ela for concluída o Código dentro do subscribe e executado(se for tudo bem com a requisição)

```
 getHour() {
    this.hourService.getData()
      .subscribe( //http disparado
        posts => this.posts = posts, //quando a requisição terminou e deu certo
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,//quando a requisição terminou e deu errado
      );     

      console.log(this.posts);//aqui o http ainda não terminou por isso o undefined
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, foi exatamente o que aprendi sobre isso.

Estou usando um promise para utilizar os dados depois que eles foram coletados e atribuídos dentro do subscribe.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode guardar esse retorno dentro de uma variável global.

```
var posts = this.posts;
```

Comment: opá, legal, mas a variável sempre fica vazia em tempo de execução.

Eu tento utilizar os dados em outra função ou mesmo usar esta variável para depois apresentar na tela, e a mesma sempre fica vazia.

Comment: declara a variável fora da função, dentro de um scopo global e dentro da função apenas atribua o valor a ela.